# how to make this switch case statement less verbose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_USER_REQUEST':
    case 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS':
    case 'FETCH_USER_FAILIURE':
      return { ...state, loading: action.payload.loading, ...action.payload.data };
    case 'UPDATE_USER_REQUEST':
    case 'UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS':
    case 'UPDATE_USER_FAILIURE':
      return { ...state, loading: action.payload.loading, ...action.payload.data };
```

currently I have a switch statement like this, as you can see I am calling REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE constantly. I want a function that creates a case that lets me check for 
'FETCH_USER', and it'll create the cases for the REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE.

I have tried something like `case action.type.includes('FETCH_USER')` however this would just match the first result of 'FETCH_USER_REQUEST' and return that. So I need a function make the three cases in that order.

Comment: does the switch statement work? where is the difference?

Comment: The problem is not the switch, but the redux anti-pattern you are using. This [article](https://itnext.io/the-perils-of-using-a-common-redux-anti-pattern-344d778e59da) will give you more information.

Comment: it does work, but i don't want to have to  specif (REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILIURE) everytime. I rather have a function that would abstract that so i can just check for case 'FETCH_USER' and it would imply the request, success, failure are also cases

Comment: Maybe you should split up things in the `type` property. Have separate properties for the operation and the state. `operation: 'FETCH_USER', state: 'SUCCESS'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the last word from the string.

```
switch (action.type.replace(/_[^_]*$/, '') {
    case 'FETCH_USER':
        return ...
    case 'UPDATE_USER':
        return ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, it can be replaced with a simple `if` statement:

```
if (/(FETCH|UPDATE)_USER/.test(action.type))
      return { ...state, loading: action.payload.loading, ...action.payload.data };
```